# pyodbc to SQL Server too slow while fetching results

Tags: python, sql, performance, pyodbc

I am using jupiter notebook with Python 3 and connecting to a SQL server database. I am using pyodbc version 4.0.22 to connect to the database.

My goal is to store the SQL results in a pandas dataframe, but the query was so slow.

Here is the code:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=ISTPRD02;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
ontem = '20180521'

query = "SELECT LOJA, COUNT(DISTINCT RA) FROM VENDAS_CONTRATO(NOLOCK) WHERE DT_RETIRADA_RA = '" + ontem + "' AND SITUACAO IN ('ABERTO', 'FECHADO') GROUP BY LOJA"
start = time.time()
ra_ontem = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn)
end = time.time()
print("Tempo: ", end - start)
```

Tempo:  26.379971981048584

Since it took a long time, I have monitored the database server, and it takes about 3 seconds to run the query on the server, as you can see below:

```
query = "SELECT LOJA, COUNT(DISTINCT RA)  FROM VENDAS_CONTRATO(NOLOCK) WHERE DT_RETIRADA_RA = '" + ontem + "' AND SITUACAO IN ('ABERTO', 'FECHADO') GROUP BY LOJA"
start = time.time()
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute(query)
end = time.time()
print("Tempo: ", end - start)
```

Tempo:  3.7947773933410645

```
start = time.time()
crsr.fetchone()
end = time.time()
print("Tempo: ", end - start)
```

Tempo:  0.2396855354309082

```
start = time.time()
crsr.fetchall()
end = time.time()
print("Tempo: ", end - start)
```

Tempo:  23.67447066307068

So it seams that my problem is local, when the data is already retrieved from the database server and it looks like the pyhton code is slow when dealing with the data.

But I have only 892 lines !

```
ra_ontem.shape
```

(189, 2)

So my question is how can I make this faster and load the results into a Pandas Dataframe ?

Thanks

Comment: 892 lines (you mean rows right?) but how many bytes are transferred?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Rows!! One column is a 3 digit text and the count is integer. I dont know how many bytes were transferred but I supose a few.. How can I check this? Load into pandas and see how many bytes are used? Thanks

Comment: This may be, don't know panda :( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, it was just because tracing is switched on.
Just open up ODBC Data Source Administrator and go to the Tracing tab and turn off tracing. It completely solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you a bit faster than usual

```
cursor.execute(query)

df = cursor.fetchallarrow().to_pandas()
```

Comment: `fetchallarrow` appears to be a turbodbc thing. pyodbc has no such method.

Comment: yeah you are right. i forgot to mention, use turbodbc its lot more faster than pyodbc in some cases

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with pyodbc but is with sql-server. your code has two problems:
1) you need to create indecies on the columns which appear in "WHERE" clause.(i.e.  DT_RETIRADA and  SITUACAO ). Please note that if you always filter SITUACAO  with those two values constantly, you can use filtered index. If you have index on these two field the best solution is to rebuild  the index.
2) you query most probably suffers from "parameter sniffing". you need to search more about that